Can you take a class as an argument and build a type from it?
I have a function that takes a class as an argument, and uses an interface based on that class as a type.
Everything works great when I take the type as a generic type argument:
class SomeClass{}

interface SomeClassType extends SomeClass {}

// Use them together
doSomething<SomeClassType>(SomeClass, 1234);

// Example doSomething function
const doSomething = <T,> (
  // I found this "type for a class" in another SO post, but I'm
  // not sure it's correct, and it may be the root of my problem
  SomeClass: { new(...args: any[]): any; },
  x: any
) => {
  // Does something with x, SomeClass, and T
}

However, it felt redundant to have to pass T and SomeClass, so I figured, why not pass just the class, and derive its type inside my function? So, I tried to do that:
const doSomething = (
  SomeClass: { new(...args: any[]): any; },
  x: any
) => {
  interface T extends SomeClass {}
  // Does something with x, SomeClass, and T
}

However, that gets me an error:

'SomeClass' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof SomeClass'?ts(2749)

Can you pass a class as an argument, and then create a type from it, and if so how?

This user has recently deleted an identical question because, apparently, requests for a [mre] without issues were asking for "pointless details". Maybe someone else will have better luck than me, but be warned.

It's not important what the function does, but it is important what it does with the passed class. Do you want to instantiate it? Call static methods? Do something else?

Where is T used in the code? Why are the class and the interface empty? Please put at least some dummy properties/methods in there.

What does any of that have to do with passing classes as arguments?  It literally does not matter one iota what I do with the class. This is a simple question about passing classes in TS and making types from them: if you don't want to answer, please don't

@machineghost There is no vendatta here, he's not following anyone but he's just very active on TypeScript questions. And his remarks are on point. Please do not delete and repost your questions.

@machineghost "What does any of that have to do with passing classes as arguments?" - because without that information, doSomething = (SomeClass: unknown, x: any): void => {} is the solution you would get. Which is probably not what you're looking for. So what are your constraints?

You still need the generic. You just need to use it in the type of the class - it looks like you want T to be the type of the class instances, which is the return type of the constructor:
const doSomething = <T,> (
  SomeClass: { new(): T; },
//                    ^
  x: unknown
) => {
  // …
}

Then T can be inferred from the class object you're passing.

But then how do I make the type from the class inside the function?

You don't "make" another type inside function. T is that type.

@machineghost Yes, it still required a lot of guesswork about the relationshipt between T and SomeClass. It would've been much simpler if you had shown the const y: T = new SomeClass() part that surely is part of the function's code somewhere

I did! interface SomeClassType extends SomeClass {} was how I was doing it before.  I didn't know how to derive the type in the arg: I only knew how to make a type from a class using extends.  That syntax where I make the type from the class as I declare it was the very syntax  I was trying to learn by asking the question.

Actually, I realize this doesn't solve it: you're not making the type in that code, you're still passing it in.  I guess it just isn't possible to make it inside the function from the class arg :(

It should be correctly inferred though if you call doSomething(SomeClass, 1234); without explicitly passing it. It is not possible to "make" a type inside the function that depends on the runtime value of the parameter, if you want different types for different passed classes then your function must be generic. (If you don't, then you could declare the static type inside or outside the function, no difference). But again, you haven't really shown what you need the type for inside the function, so I can only guess.
